# How to change value of current array/ object only using ngmodel angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ngmodel

I have an array and an object. In array I am getting a list from my service and in object I am assigning first element of that array.

```
feesEntries: Array<any> = [];
selectedFeesEntry: any;
clientList: Array<any> = [];

getData(data){
   this.feesEntries = JSON.parse(data['_body']);
   this.selectedFeesEntry = this.feesEntries[0];
}
```

On UI A table is displayed from the `feesEntries` array. I have a dropdown to select clients and for options I have `ClientList` & `ngModel` is used to bind select to `selectedFeesEntry`.

Sample:

```
<label class="control-label" for="select">Client Name</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <select class="form-control" id="select" [(ngModel)]="selectedFeesEntry.client.name" name="selectedClientName" (change)="onClientNameChange(selectedFeesEntry.client.name)">
          <option *ngFor="let cl of clientList" [ngValue]="cl.name">{{cl.name}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

Now the issue is when i am selecting a client from the options then using `ngmodel` only `selectedFeesEntry` should be updated but in my case `feesEntries` are also updated. I have no idea why it is happening.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post your `onClientNameChange` method?

Comment: What do you mean by "updated"?

Comment: @DGarvanski For now nothing is added in onClientNameChange method ... it is being changed by ngModel

Comment: @Chrillewoodz when i select a new client .. then my previous values are replaced by new one that is selected and it should be only true for the object that i am using in ngmodel but it is also changing my feesEntries array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I understand, When an option is selected from the dropdown, `selectedFeesEntry` changes and since you have assigned `selectedFeesEntry` like this,

```
this.selectedFeesEntry = this.feesEntries[0];
```

`selectedFeesEntry` is just a reference to `this.feesEntries[0]` or in other words, it's a **shallow copy**

To perform a deep copy,

```
this.selectedFeesEntry = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.feesEntries[0]));
```

Which will create a new object

[Example: Shallow Copy](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qgnllq)

[Example: Deep copy](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sqjdb7)

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks .. it worked... Correct me if i am wrong .. in shallow copy reference of the array is passed to the object so when the object is changed the array would be updated .... and in deep copy only the value is passed instead of reference